# changing height or width of table cell in expression

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is possible to change size of table cell in rdlc expression, if could please give me some example, I would appreciate it. Thank you very much

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/change-row-height-or-column-width-report-builder-and-ssrs?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: How would one change the size of a cell anywhere?? Only rows and columns can be sized.

Comment: I need to set row and column width and height by expression, is possible that?

Comment: @jdweng that is by design view

Comment: RDLC is text (HTML format) and you can edit with any text editor.